# which command returning undocumented things

Tags: zsh, which, datascience-anaconda

I am trying to locate which `conda` executable I am using. For this, I want to use `which` command. As per man pages, it should return the path of the executable. Instead it returns some bash function

```
(base) ➜  ~ which conda
conda () {
    \local cmd="${1-__missing__}"
    case "$cmd" in
        (activate | deactivate) __conda_activate "$@" ;;
        (install | update | upgrade | remove | uninstall) __conda_exe "$@" || \return
            __conda_reactivate ;;
        (*) __conda_exe "$@" ;;
    esac
}
```

If I try to see the location of `__conda_exe`, again I get another function:

```
__conda_exe () {
    (
        __add_sys_prefix_to_path
        "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA "$@"
    )
}
```

where is the conda function I am using?

Comment: Related: [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Comment: You've tagged your question `bash` - are you actually using `zsh` however?

Comment: If using `zsh` try typing `which -p conda` to see the path instead of the script. Starting version 4.4, conda uses a wrapper shell function to capture commands and pass it to the executable. If you want to know the version, you should use `conda --version`

Comment: yes, sorry I am using zsh!

Comment: In `zsh` `type __conda_exe` (same as `whence -v`, while `which` is `whence -c`, `c` for `csh` as `which` is initially a csh script for csh users) will tell you where the function definition was read from.

Answer (score 1):

Since you’re using [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh), I would recommend using the following:

```bash
whence -aSv conda
```

This will show you *all* the possible ways in which `conda` can be resolved.